# Calculator divide and multiply not giving expected result?

Tags: c#, calculator

I am having a problem with my calculator code. The plus and minus work as expected, however the divide and multiply end up with an answer of ZERO every time. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calculator
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btn1.Text;
    }

    private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btn2.Text;
    }

    private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btn3.Text;
    }

    private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btn4.Text;
    }

    private void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btn5.Text;
    }

    private void btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btn6.Text;
    }

    private void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btn7.Text;
    }

    private void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btn8.Text;
    }

    private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btn9.Text;
    }

    private void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btn0.Text;
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Clear();
    }

    Double total1 = 0;
    Double total2 = 0;
    bool minusButtonClicked = false;
    bool plusButtonClicked = false;
    bool divideButtonClicked = false;
    bool multiplyButtonClicked = false;

    private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        total1 = total1 + Double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        txtDisplay.Clear();

        plusButtonClicked = true;
        minusButtonClicked = false;
        divideButtonClicked = false;
        multiplyButtonClicked = false;
    }

    private void btnMinus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        total1 = total1 - Double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        txtDisplay.Clear();

        plusButtonClicked = false;
        minusButtonClicked = true;
        divideButtonClicked = false;
        multiplyButtonClicked = false;
    }

    private void btnDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        total1 = total1 / Double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        txtDisplay.Clear();

        plusButtonClicked = false;
        minusButtonClicked = false;
        divideButtonClicked = true;
        multiplyButtonClicked = false;
    }

    private void btnMultiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        total1 = total1 * Double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        txtDisplay.Clear();

        plusButtonClicked = false;
        minusButtonClicked = false;
        divideButtonClicked = false;
        multiplyButtonClicked = true;
    }

    private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (plusButtonClicked == true)
        {
            total2 = total1 + Double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        }
        else if (minusButtonClicked == true)
        {
            total2 = total1 - Double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        }
        else if (divideButtonClicked == true)
        {
            total2 = total1 / Double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        }
        else if (multiplyButtonClicked == true)
        {
            total2 = total1 * Double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        }

        txtDisplay.Text = total2.ToString();
        total1 = 0;
    }

}
}
```

Is it something in the if else statements or some other common error?

Comment: In `btnMultiply_Click`, why are you doing the multiply in the click handler? If the equation is entered as `123 * 456 =`, you should only be doing the multiply in the `=` handler.

Comment: I was following instructions of a C# book from homeandlearn. I must have missed something.

Comment: Do you ever set `total1`? It looks like it's always 0 to me unless you make a sum/difference first.

Comment: you need to spend some time thinking about what your code is doing, and looking through it with a debugger to find out where your assumptions about what should be happening are going wrong.  As it is, your question is way, way too broad as it comes down to "debug my code for me".  If the specific problem(s) you find with a debugger escape your ability to resolve then, after spending some time diagnosing and attempting to solve the problem, it may be appropriate on this site.

Comment: I set total1 in each button click event.

Comment: Servy, I did try and figure it out myself before I came here. I thought that was what this site was for was guidance. My apologies.

Comment: Funny but your total1 is always 0, and when you multiply anything with zero, or divide zero by something then number becomes zero :D

Comment: @Brandon The problem is that you're not asking a specific programming question.  You're just giving a big block of code and saying "fix it for me".  There's no real indications that you know what the problem(s) are, that you've attempted to diagnose them, attempted to fix them, etc.  In addition to that lack of effort, the question itself is just too vague and specific to your case.

Comment: @Servy I am not asking anyone to fix it for me. I was wondering if at a glance, you would see where the error was. I saw an answer though thatis was because  of the way my math was setup.

Comment: @Brandon At a glance there are many fundamental problems with the application as a whole, and since the question gives very little direction potential answers have no good way of determine what is in and out of scope, and enumerating *all* of the problems would be way too much for a single SO answer.

Comment: Shorten `if (someButtonClicked == true)` to `if (someButtonClicked)` since it's already a boolean expression.

Comment: No offense, but if this code is a result of instructions given to you by a "Learn C#" book, it's time to invest in a new book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dark Flacon said, you should do the calculation when the equals button is pressed. And you shouldn't call `total1` a total when if fact is just remembers the first number:

```
Double lastNumber = 0;
Double total = 0;
bool minusButtonClicked = false;
bool plusButtonClicked = false;
bool divideButtonClicked = false;
bool multiplyButtonClicked = false;

private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lastNumber = Double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    txtDisplay.Clear();

    plusButtonClicked = true;
    minusButtonClicked = false;
    divideButtonClicked = false;
    multiplyButtonClicked = false;
}

private void btnMinus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lastNumber = Double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    txtDisplay.Clear();

    plusButtonClicked = false;
    minusButtonClicked = true;
    divideButtonClicked = false;
    multiplyButtonClicked = false;
}

private void btnDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lastNumber = Double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    txtDisplay.Clear();

    plusButtonClicked = false;
    minusButtonClicked = false;
    divideButtonClicked = true;
    multiplyButtonClicked = false;
}

private void btnMultiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lastNumber = Double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    txtDisplay.Clear();

    plusButtonClicked = false;
    minusButtonClicked = false;
    divideButtonClicked = false;
    multiplyButtonClicked = true;
}

private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (plusButtonClicked == true)
    {
        total = lastNumber + Double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    }
    else if (minusButtonClicked == true)
    {
        total = lastNumber - Double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    }
    else if (divideButtonClicked == true)
    {
        total = lastNumber / Double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    }
    else if (multiplyButtonClicked == true)
    {
        total = lastNumber * Double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    }

    txtDisplay.Text = total.ToString();
    lastNumber = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 3):

You initialize total1 and total2 to 0.

Your code:

```
total1 = total1 * Double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
```

will always give you 0 because 0 * #anynumber# = 0.

Same thing with division: 0 / #anynumber# = 0.

You could organize your code not to use so many boolean flags, but that's not really your problem, anyhow.